# Desktop-ная версия сайта на мобильном телефоне

Tags: html, css

Заказчица говорит, что на ее мобильном телефоне есть кнопка "посмотреть полную версию сайта". Скидывает мне скрины в которых половина стилей для десктопа, половина - с мобилы. Что делать?

Можно ли как-то это запретить или там что-то еще?

Comment: Не "на ее телефоне", а в ее мобильном браузере. Сейчас сложно найти браузер без такой опции. Это чаще всего работает так: сайту посылается ложный User-Agent, а оригинальный viewport игнорируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже указал комментатор выше - да, в современных мобильных браузерах есть кнопка показать полную версию сайта. Отменить это довольно сложно, по скольку как уже тоже было написано: телефон посылает неверный вьюпорт.
Здесь можно только порекомендовать задавать все стили по принципу @media all and (min-width: 640) для пк и @media all and (max-width: 639) для мобильного, так как большинство современных мобильных телефонов имеют hd разрешение (то бишь 720px с наименьшей стороны дисплея), что значит, что при включении "полной версии" она увидит версию именно для пк (720>640, значит показывает пкшную версию), а без такого свойства именно для мобильных.